# difference between <bdi> and <span dir="auto">

Tags: html, bidi

In the following HTML, both `<bdi>` and `<span dir="auto">` seem to behave the same:

```html
<p dir="auto">
<bdi>ABC תתת DEF</bdi>
אבג דהו.
</p>

<p dir="auto">
<span dir="auto">ABC תתת DEF</span>
אבג דהו.
</p>
```

I could not find any case where they behave differently, so my question is:

Is there any difference between them? Is there ever a reason to use `<bdi>` over `dir="auto"`? Especially if I want to apply it to an element that already exists in my HTML, for example `<a>`:

```html
<p dir="auto"><a href="http://example.com" dir="auto">http://example.com</a> טקסט טקסט</p>
<p dir="auto"><bdi><a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a></bdi> טקסט טקסט</p>
```

The version with `<bdi>` has some unnecessary nesting.

If `dir="auto"` accomplishes the same thing, then why does `<bdi>` exist?

Comment: bdi is poorly supported across browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=bdi

Comment: Good point, but the question is about whether there **should** be a special meaning for `<bdi>` where it's supported, and whether it can be **entirely** replaced with `<span dir="auto">` without caveats.

Comment: @Gerard Which is weird, considering it’s been officially standardized for almost exactly five years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdi):

> Embedding the characters in `<span dir="auto">` has the same effect as using `<bdi>`, but its semantics are less clear.

[The spec also confirms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-dir-attribute) that the behavior is the same by grouping the same algorithm under both conditions (`dir="auto"` attribute or `<bdi>` element).

In other words: If the element to which you're applying `dir="auto"` is a phrasing element that isn't a `<span>` and already carries its own semantics (such as the `<a>` in your example), it's better to use the attribute to save the nesting overhead of a `<bdi>` element. If it's a `<span>`, an element that has no semantic meaning on its own, you're better off using the dedicated `<bdi>` element instead. It's the same in principle as preferring `<main>` over `<div role="main">`, or `<nav>` over `<div role="navigation">`.

Comment: Thank you! For completeness you might want to mention the poor cross-browser support mentioned in the comments, as that's a good reason to actually avoid `<bdi>`, but this is a full answer to my question :)

Comment: @NeatNit: I had considered it, but I need to do more research into both features to see if support is comparable or if the global dir=auto has significantly better support to warrant not using <bdi>.